# How to use the Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies subplugin in R

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm building an interactive map in Leaflet using R, and I would like to use the [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies](https://github.com/adammertel/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies) sub-plugin to control the placement of markers within a cluster (when "spiderfied" on mouse click over the cluster), and always lay them out in a circle around the cluster icon, rather than along a spiral as it happens when there are more than 8 markers in a cluster with the standard Leaflet.MarkerCluster plugin that comes embedded in the leaflet htmlWidget.  The code I'm using to build the map is something like this:

```
library(leaflet)

data_example <- data.frame(name = rep("site A", times = 14),
                   lon = rep(14.25000, times = 14),
                   lat = rep(40.83333, times = 14),
                   issue = paste("Issue", LETTERS[1:14]),
                   severity = sample(c("Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"), size = 14, replace = TRUE))

issues_pal <- colorFactor(brewer.pal(3, "RdYlBu"), levels = c("Mild", "Moderate", "Severe"), reverse = TRUE)

leaflet(data_example, options = leafletOptions(maxZoom = 7)) %>% 
  setView(lng = 8, lat = 50, zoom = 4) %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldStreetMap) %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(
    lng = ~ lon,
    lat = ~ lat,
    radius = 10,
    color = "grey",
    weight = 2,
    fillColor = ~ issues_pal(severity),
    #stroke = FALSE, 
    fillOpacity = 0.8,
    label = ~ paste(issue, severity),
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
        spiderfyDistanceMultiplier = 1.1, 
        spiderLegPolylineOptions = list(weight = 0)),
    group = df,
    clusterId = df
  )
```

In the map, when one clicks on the cluster icon, the markers are shown placed along a spiral path originating from the cluster. This is because the Leaflet.MarkerCluster plugin that control the clustering of markers in leaflet, place them along a circle only when there are up to 8 markers. But the Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies should allow to specify a different placement strategy, and to have markers laid out in a circle even if they are more than 8, as shown in this [page](https://adammertel.github.io/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies/demo/demo1.html) and [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adammertel/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies/master/assets/img_strategy_onecircle.png).

Since the sub-plugin is not yet included in leaflet package, I'd like to use the method highlighted [here](https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/c084a59717f18e947a17955007dc5f92) to use in R any leaflet JS plugins, but I'm struggling to find a way to make it work for my case. According to the method, I should first of all include the following in my code:

```
placement.strategies <- htmlDependency(
  "Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies",
  "0.0.1", 
  src = c(href = "https://github.com/adammertel/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.PlacementStrategies/blob/master/dist/"),
  script = "leaflet-markercluster.placementstrategies.src.js"
)

registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
  map
}
```

And then I should call `registerPlugin(placement.strategies)` in the leaflet pipe.  However, I can't figure out how to adapt the following custom JS code to my needs:

```
leaflet() %>% setView(lng = 8, lat = 50, zoom = 4) %>%
  # Register plugin on this map instance
  registerPlugin(placement.strategies) %>%
  # Add your custom JS logic here. The `this` keyword
  # refers to the Leaflet (JS) map object.
  onRender("function(el, x) {
    L.esri.basemapLayer('Topographic').addTo(this);
  }")
```

I've tried to simply specify in the call to `addCircleMarkers()` the `elementsPlacementStrategy = 'one-circle'` as a clusterOption within the `markerClusterOptions()`, but it does not work.  I suspect the JS code I need to call from should somehow modify the option property `elementsPlacementStrategy` for the cluster, but how to do that I don't know. Can anyone help with this?  Thank you in advance!

#### post scriptum

I have found a way around to get the circle placement without using the subplugin, that involves modifying in the leaflet.markercluster.js file the `_circleSpiralSwitchover` property to a number greater than 14 (that is the number of markers I have in the cluster). While this workaround achieves the result I wanted, it is sub-optimal, because unless I decide to modify the default .js file that is located in:

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/leaflet/htmlwidgets/plugins/Leaflet.markercluster

I would need to remake the edit on the .js file every time I export the map with `saveWidget`.